# Regex to remove text after a comma and the following word

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex that removes all text after a comma and the space+word after the comma.

So if I have the string:

"123 some address, place 2800 Australia"

I want to remove " 2800 Australia". The word "place" can be anything so the regex needs to match a word not the specified "place" string.

So far I have this as working best:

```
var s = '123 some address, place 2800 Australia';
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(', '));
document.write(s);
```

However this will of course also remove "place" and I need the first word after the comma to still be included.

Thanks!

Comment: How is this related to jQuery?

Comment: is it possible for the string to have more than one comma ?

Comment: @Sven.hig There is a possibility, yes.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry about that, I am looking for a solution in JQuery (if possible) I have just been playing around with vanilla JavaScript hence the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `split()`, `replace()`, `match()` function with some ReGex - This was a bit tricky as i had to consider two `commas` scenarios as well.

First we can use `match` the `commas` in the string get the address only then you can use the get the place and `split` from the space `" "`

After that we can consider two commas scenario which will be after the `place` so we can check by using `replace()` and replace with nothing.

Lastly its not possible with using `jQuery` as `jQuery` is `Javascript`.

**Having one comma**

```js
var text = '123 some address, place 2800 Australia';

//Match and get Address
var addr = text.match(/([^,]*)(.*)/)[1];

//Match and get place with split
var place = text.match(/([^,]*),(.*)/)[2].split(' ')[1]
   
//New Address
var newAdd = addr + ', ' + place 

//Write
document.write(newAdd);

//Console.log
console.log(newAdd);
```

**Having two commas** (possibility)

The solution works for two commas as well.

```js
var text = '123 some address, place, 2800 Australia';

//Match and get Address
var addr = text.match(/([^,]*)(.*)/)[1];

//Match and get place with split
var place = text.match(/([^,]*),(.*)/)[2].split(' ')[1]

//If two commas
var ifTwoCommas = place.replace(',', '');

//New Address
var newAdd = addr + ', ' + ifTwoCommas

//Write
document.write(newAdd);

//Console.log
console.log(newAdd);
```